# Error building schema with gatsby-source-filesystem config (following official tutorial)

Tags: javascript, plugins, config, gatsby

I'm learning Gatsby by following the tutorial on https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-five/#source-plugins, but got stuck trying to configure the *gatsby-source-filesystem* in *gatsby-config.js*.

I'm just using the simple gatsby config file as in the tuto:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Pandas Eating Lots`,
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `src`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-emotion`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-typography`,
      options: {
        pathToConfigModule: `src/utils/typography`,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

And I get the following error when I start the dev server:

```
$ gatsby develop
success open and validate gatsby-configs - 0.036s
success load plugins - 0.199s
success onPreInit - 0.010s
success initialize cache - 0.025s
success copy gatsby files - 0.052s
success onPreBootstrap - 0.013s
success createSchemaCustomization - 0.002s
success source and transform nodes - 0.091s
⠋ building schema

 ERROR 

UNHANDLED REJECTION File.publicURL provided incorrect OutputType: 'String'



  Error: File.publicURL provided incorrect OutputType: 'String'

  - TypeMapper.js:294 TypeMapper.convertOutputFieldConfig
    [tutorial-part-four]/[graphql-compose]/lib/TypeMapper.js:294:15

  - configAsThunk.js:19 resolveOutputConfigAsThunk
    [tutorial-part-four]/[graphql-compose]/lib/utils/configAsThunk.js:19:41

  - ObjectTypeComposer.js:300 ObjectTypeComposer.getFieldConfig
    [tutorial-part-four]/[graphql-compose]/lib/ObjectTypeComposer.js:300:58

  - toInputObjectType.js:44 fieldNames.forEach.fieldName
    [tutorial-part-four]/[graphql-compose]/lib/utils/toInputObjectType.js:44:19

  - Array.forEach

  - toInputObjectType.js:38 toInputObjectType
    [tutorial-part-four]/[graphql-compose]/lib/utils/toInputObjectType.js:38:14

  - ObjectTypeComposer.js:600 ObjectTypeComposer.getInputTypeComposer
    [tutorial-part-four]/[graphql-compose]/lib/ObjectTypeComposer.js:600:84

  - sort.js:54 getSortInput
    [tutorial-part-four]/[gatsby]/dist/schema/types/sort.js:54:42

  - schema.js:1104 addTypeToRootQuery
    [tutorial-part-four]/[gatsby]/dist/schema/schema.js:1104:23

  - schema.js:270 processTypeComposer
    [tutorial-part-four]/[gatsby]/dist/schema/schema.js:270:13

⠋ building schema
$
```

I'm using Node version 10.16.3

I tried to search but didn't find useful information about this specific error.

Can anyone help please? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Updating `gatsby-source-filesystem` might fix the issue for you.

https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/20718#issuecomment-787009213