# Error building schema with gatsby-source-filesystem config with officiel tutorial

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, config, gatsby

I'm quite new to using Gatsby and for this reason I wanted to start using it by following the official tutorial. Everything went well until I came across the 4th part of it : https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/tutorial/part-4/#task-use-graphiql-to-build-the-query-1

When I update my `gatsby-config.js` file with the `gatsby-source-filesystem` configuration, I can't run my website locally.

When running the `gatsby develop` command in my terminal, I have the following error when trying to build schema :

```
gatsby develop    

success compile gatsby files - 1.288s 
success load gatsby config - 0.013s 
success load plugins - 0.303s 
success onPreInit - 0.004s 
success initialize cache - 0.074s 
success copy gatsby files - 0.049s 
success Compiling Gatsby Functions - 0.080s 
success onPreBootstrap - 0.087s 
success createSchemaCustomization - 0.002s 
success Checking for changed pages - 0.002s 
success source and transform nodes - 0.089s

 ERROR 

Missing onError handler for invocation 'building-schema', error was 'Error: TypeError[File.publicURL]: Cannot convert to OutputType the following value: Object({ type: String, args: Object({  }), description: "Copy file to static directory and return public url to it", resolve: [function resolve] })'. Stacktrace was 'Error: TypeError[File.publicURL]: Cannot convert to OutputType the following value: Object({ type: String, args: Object({  }), description: "Copy file to static directory and return public url to it", resolve: [function resolve] })
    at TypeMapper.convertOutputFieldConfig (/Users/nicolas/my-gatsby-site/node_m odules/graphql-compose/src/TypeMapper.ts:419:13)
    at ObjectTypeComposer.setField (/Users/nicolas/my-gatsby-site/node_modules/g raphql-compose/src/ObjectTypeComposer.ts:445:40)
    at /Users/nicolas/my-gatsby-site/node_modules/graphql-compose/src/ObjectType Composer.ts:479:14
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ObjectTypeComposer.addNestedFields (/Users/nicolas/my-gatsby-site/node_mo dules/graphql-compose/src/ObjectTypeComposer.ts:468:28)
    at forEach (/Users/nicolas/my-gatsby-site/node_modules/gatsby/src/schema/schema.js:764:39)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/nicolas/my-gatsby-site/node_modules/gatsby/src/schema/schema.js:764:18
    at async Promise.all (index 54)
    at updateSchemaComposer (/Users/nicolas/my-gatsby-site/node_modules/gatsby/src/schema/schema.js:168:3)
    at buildSchema (/Users/nicolas/my-gatsby-site/node_modules/gatsby/src/schema/schema.js:71:3)
    at build (/Users/nicolas/my-gatsby-site/node_modules/gatsby/src/schema/index.js:112:18)
    at buildSchema (/Users/nicolas/my-gatsby-site/node_modules/gatsby/src/servic es/build-schema.ts:19:3)'

⠸ building schema
```

Then the `building schema` command is running forever and my site can't launch.

I know the issue is when adding `gatsby-source-filesystem` into the `gatsby-config.js` file because when I delete it, I can run `gatsby develop` without any issue.

Here is my `gatsby-config.js` file, nearly identical to the one in the tutorial (I just changed the blog title) :

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Arckablog`,
    siteUrl: `https://www.yourdomain.tld`,
  },
  plugins: [
    "gatsby-plugin-image",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp",
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
      options: {
        name: `blog`,
        path: `${__dirname}/blog`,
      }
    },
  ],
}
```

I have seen a similar question on stackoverflow here : [Error building schema with gatsby-source-filesystem config (following official tutorial)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60022341/error-building-schema-with-gatsby-source-filesystem-config-following-official-t) and I tried updating both my Gatsby version and the `gatsby-source-filesystem` version but none of it worked out for me.

Can you maybe advise me please ?

Thank you for your help !

Nicolas

Answer (score 2):

I encountered same problem.
I was running
`npm install gatsby-source-filesystem`
from different folder. Then I changed my current folder to project directory and ran `npm install gatsby-source-filesystem` everything worked fine